# Moment.js convert MM/dd/yyyy format date

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

i have textbox when user enter data with MM/dd/yyyy format then i need to parse that data and convert it to date. i used momentjs but my code not working. here is my code snippet.

```
var otherProp = $('#' + param.otherproperty);
var StartDate = new date(moment(otherProp.val(), 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
```

specially this line is not working `var StartDate = new date(moment(otherProp.val(), 'MM/dd/yyyy'));` where i made the mistake ?
thanks

### UPDATE

my full code as follows

```
$.validator.addMethod("isgreater", function (value, element, param) {
    var otherProp = $('#' + param.otherproperty);
    var StartDate = new Date(moment(otherProp.val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY'));

    var Enddate = new Date(value);
    if (StartDate != '')
    {
        return Enddate >= StartDate;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `new date` is a typo for `new Date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert all of the `MM/dd/yyyy` to uppercase `MM/DD/YYYY`

so this should work

```
var otherProp = $('#' + param.otherproperty);
var StartDate = new Date(moment(otherProp.val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
```